# Append a table onto a svg by id using d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Below is my code, the table does not show up. With Chrome's developer/elements shows the  elemnts are created but I don't see it when the browser render it. The data is correct since the  elemnts show up under developer/elements.

```
<svg id="abc" width="100%" height="100%"
          viewBox="-20 -20 800 800" 
          preserveAspectRatio="none"></svg>

function createSpreadsheet(incData){
var keyValues = d3.keys(incData[0])

    d3.select("#abc")
    .append("table")

    d3.select("table")
    .append("tr")
    .attr("class", "head")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(keyValues)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .html(function (d) {return d})

    d3.select("table")
    .selectAll("tr.data")
    .data(incData).enter()
    .append("tr")
    .attr("class", "data")

    d3.selectAll("tr")
    .selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d) {return d3.entries(d)})
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .html(function (d) {return d.value})
}
d3.json("data.json", function(error,data){

 createSpreadsheet(data)

)}


data=[{'A':'123', 'B':'456'}, {'A':'321', 'B':'654'}]
```

Comment: Your table will never show up. You *cannot* append any HTML tag (div, h1, p, table etc) to an SVG (unless using foreignObject). And the dev tools will show the elements, because it will shou *any* element. Try this: `d3.select("#abc").append("dolphin");`. You're gonna see `<svg><dolphin></dolphin></svg>`, which makes no sense.

Comment: In your function `createSpreadsheet`, try `d3.select("body")` or any other HTML div, and your table probably will show up.

Comment: I think @GerardoFurtado you should move this as the answer, wondering why its a comment.

Comment: Hi, Cyril, I'm developing the terrible SO habit of answering in the comments! But seriously, I didn't answer because this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a foreign object inside SVG to be able to insert Table into it...

do this to create a foreign object inside ur SVG and then add table to this object

```
 var table =  d3.select("#abc")
    .append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500)
    .append("xhtml:table");

table.append("tr")
     .attr("class", "head")
     .selectAll("th")
     .data(keyValues)
     .enter()
     .append("th")
     .html(function (d) {return d})
```

Comment: This will not work on Internet Explorer. I'd advise the OP to append the table to other HTML element instead.

Comment: yes.. this will not work on IE. Not sure if that's a requirement. Otherwise... this works and is supported on all major browsers.